# Looking for the title of a book...

Tags: reference-request

I remember there was a book for kids, which taught algebra through a story. The story was like this:

There was some land, in which some people lived whose main job was to count. They didn't know algebra they only knew arithmetic. Some day a magician appeared and asked them to solve a question (which required algebra) and threatened them that if they can't do that, he would do something terrible (I don't remember the details).

And from then on the quest for the answer to the question would begin which would teach algebra concepts through the story.

It's about 3 hours I'm searching the web with no success. The book is kinda old. But I did have a pdf file of it. I couldn't find the pdf on my backups and I couldn't find the book on the web.

So I thought I would ask here; probably someone knows which book I'm talking about.

Thanks a lot

Edit: The book had pictures and it was English.

Comment: Do you remember if it  was originally written in English or translated from another language ?

Comment: Was it illustrated?

Comment: Yes. It had pictures and it was English.

Comment: I think a way to spot such a book is to look for its front cover. I have done a Google search with "old illustrated children's books arithmetic algebra" and ask for "images"... yielding more than 100 titles

Comment: Was it possibly in the "Math Adventures" series?

Comment: @Raj 
I don't really think it was a "series".

Comment: @JeanMarie

I did this but wasn't able to find it. (In fact I don't really remember the cover much but I think if I see the title I'll remember)